# Создание jar файла

Tags: ant, jar, java, intellij-idea, eclipse

Как создать библиотеку Java? Как я понимаю, надо сделать jar-пакет? Как его правильно создавать? Есть ли автоматизированные средства в Эклипсе или в Идее? Можно ли добавить отдельный таргет в ant-скрипт?

Answer (score 2):

Тут все просто и доступно:
http://www.javable.com/javaworld/tips/120_tt/

А в Eclipse, если память не изменяет: File -> Export -> Jar file...

Comment: Главное удалите все ресурсы, чтобы ничего не дублировалось при сборке проекта (отслеживайте этот момент в консоли внимательно).

Answer (score 1):

В IDEA можно автоматизировать добавив артефакт сборки и в конструкторе jar'а добавить результаты сборки

UPD: [IntelliJ IDEA 10.0 Web Help: Configuring Artifacts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html)

Comment: Можно подробнее? Или где почитать?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/540  (этот вопрос есть справа в графе "Связанные вопросы")