# Как в Intellj Idea подключить к проекту файлы class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, компиляция

Есть папка и в ней лежат уже скомпилированные классы. Как из них вызвать методы? Закинул в каталог проекта, и написал

```
import javax.help;
```

В результате Error:(15, 18) java: package javax.help does not exist.

Comment: т.е. вы просто добавили файлы .class в проект?

Comment: вам по-идеии нужно все эти файлы .class запаковать в .jar архив, а потом подключить .jar библиотеку в свой проект, гляньте тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3754/191718

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример из консоли

Структура каталогов:

```
C:\dev\
  TestImp.class
c:\dev\mypack\
  Test.class
```

Код класса Test:

```
package mypack;

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        System.out.println("I live!");
    }
}
```

Код класса TestImp:

```
import mypack.Test;

public class TestImp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test t = new Test();
   }
}
```

В консоли переходим в каталог c:\dev\ и выполняем:

```
java TestImp
```

В консоль выводится:

```
I live!
```

**UPD:**

Что касается Intellj Idea - вам требуется запаковать ваши файлы классов в jar командой

```
jar cf test.jar Test1.class
```

После этого импортируете jar в проект следующим образом:

```
Структура проекта (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
Modules на левой панели.
Вкладка Dependencies
'+' → JARs or directories
```

**UPD2:**

Intellij IDEA позволяет добавлять не только JAR'ы, но и каталоги с классами. Делается полностью аналогично написанному выше, только выбирается каталог с классами. После выбора откроется диалог, в котором можно исключить какие либо подкаталоги выбранного каталога.

Comment: Вовсе не обязательно паковать в jar, можно подключить к проекту саму папку с class-файлами.

Comment: @Roman попробую вечером и если подтвердится, то отредактирую ответ.

Comment: @Roman работает и с папками тоже. Дополнил ответ.